# transpose a table using talend

Tags: csv, talend

I would like to transpose a table like the one below:
[image]

into this:
[image]

I wanted to mention that the files are CSV files.

Thanks,

Comment: You can use the following component "tPivotToColumnsDelimited" : https://help.talend.com/reader/jomWd_GKqAmTZviwG_oxHQ/x2GUXKMQs_wrCX0kdZDwDg

Comment: Thank you Theo for your reply, however the tPivotToColumnsDelimited did not transpose the data. It stayed as is.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution to this, but it's inelegant and inefficient and may not work incase of a huge dataset (may run out of memory).

You can denormalise the whole input, by defining all the schema columns in the *tDenormalize* component, pass it across to a *tMap* to concatenate all the columns using a special character in between. The special character is just an identifier for the next component we are going to use.
Connect the *tMaps* output to a *tNormalize* and use the special character as the Item Seperator while the column to normalise should be the only column (which you concatenated to in the previous *tMap*) available.
This should do what you're looking for. If you wish to process the data after this instead of just transposing, you can use *tExtractDelimitedFields* component and use the "," as your field Seperator since its a csv.